# Iteration over dict in list

Tags: python, django

```
[{u'name': u'xxx', u'age': u'11'}, {u'name': u'myname', u'age': u'2'}, {u'name': u'cat', u'age': u'8'}]
```

How can I add my data from list above (json.loads result) into queryset.

```
mydata.details.add(MyDetails.objects.create(name=NAME_FROM_MY_LIST), age=AGE_FROM_MY_LIST)
```

This should be iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the list items:

```
data = [{u'name': u'xxx', u'age': u'11'}, {u'name': u'myname', u'age': u'2'}, {u'name': u'cat', u'age': u'8'}]
for obj in data:
    mydata.details.add(MyDetails.objects.create(name=obj['name']), age=obj['age'])
```

As `data` is a list of “things”, you can get each “thing” by iterating over the list. And then, as each “thing” happens to be a dict containing information, you can just read from that dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
for record in my_list:
    mydata.details.add(MyDetails.objects.create(name=record['name'], age=record['age'])
```